# AngularJs + RequireJs filter Unknown provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I have problem with how to inject filter properly, issue appear only on production, on my localhost all correct, I thought that filter loads before angular, but I've put breakpoints and see that all going correct this way ( or I miss something ) Looks like problem with deps. injection, but I can't find proper way.

Here is my files, please help, I break my head with this issue.

boot.js

```
window.name = 'NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP!';
require.config({
  'baseUrl': '/static/angular/',
  'paths': {
    /* .... */ 
  },
  'shim': {
    /* .... */ 
  }
});
require([
  'angular',
  'app'
], function (angular, app) {
  'use strict';
  angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]);
  angular.element().ready(function () {
    angular.resumeBootstrap([app.name]);
  });
});
```

app.js

```
define([
  'angular',
  'filters/filters',
  'controllers'
], function (angular) {
  /* .... */
  return app;
});
```

controllers.js

```
define( function (require) {
  'use strict';
  var angular = require('angular'),
      Controllers = angular.module('controllers', []);
  Controllers.controller('mainController', require('controllers/main.controller'));
  /* .... */
  return Controllers;
});
```

filters/filters.js

```
require([
  'app'
], function (app) {
  'use strict';
  app.filter('yesNo', function() {
    /* .... */
  });
  return app;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way, now I'm creating filters module and instead of pass app dependency I'm sending angular object and inject new module :

filters/filters.js

```
require([
  'angular'
], function (angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('filters', []).filter('yesNo', function() {
    /* .... */
  });
});
```

app.js

```
define([
  'angular',
  'filters/filters',
], function (angular) {
  'use strict';
  var app = angular.module('appName', [
    'filters',
  ]);
  /* .... */
  return app;
});
```

Now it works correct!